# ESLint `import/no-named-export` how to enable with exceptions

Tags: eslint, eslintrc, eslint-plugin-import

I have named exports disabled in NextJS' `pages/` and (now) `app/` folders. If it is relevant. I have a root config that disabled default exports for the entire application. Then those two folders have an `.eslintrc` to override and flip the relevant rules.

*Root `.eslintrc` rules*

```json
{
  "root": true,
  "rules": {
    "import/no-default-export": "error",
    "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
    "import/no-named-export": "off"
  }
}
```

*`app/` and `pages/` `.eslintrc` rules*

```json
{
  "ignorePatterns": ["middleware.ts", "./**/middleware.ts"],
  "rules": {
    "import/no-default-export": "off",
    "import/prefer-default-export": "error",
    "import/no-named-export": "error"
  },
  "root": false
}
```

Is there a way to create an exception for their known valid exports? i.e. `getServerSideProps`